# How to get hold of time in the format of "2023-04-17" of following HTML code using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="medium-widget event-widget last">
    <div class="shrubbery">
        <h2 class="widget-title">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-calendar"></span>Upcoming Events
        </h2>
        <p class="give-me-more">
            <a href="/events/calendars/" title="More Events">More</a>
        </p>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <time datetime="2023-04-17T00:00:00+00:00">
                    <span class="say-no-more">2023-</span>04-17 </time>
                <a href="/events/python-events/1380/">PyCon DE &amp; PyData Berlin 2023</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>undefinedundefined</div>
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
event_times = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/time')
for time in event_times:
    print(time.text)
```

Also tried using

```
find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.medium-widget event-widget last.time")
```

but this code is not found responsive

Answer (score 0):

```
event_times = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//time/@datetime')
for time in event_times:
     print(time.text)
```

##### find_element     return:      first one

##### find_elements    return:      list

Comment: Thank You for your answer

event_times = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".event-widget time")

This Code works fine and fatches the data according to the format i mentioned in the Q.
But there 5 sequences of the date SAME as like above HTML code. 

And I m getting another error while iterating through the for loop to get all the date Data :

for time in event_times:
    print(time.text)

Comment: For the knowledge of selenium, I have forgotten some, and I am thinking about it step by step. I am really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML provided, you can use a simple CSS selector to get the TIME element and then extract the `datetime` attribute to get the datetime string, "2023-04-17T00:00:00+00:00". This is an ISO 8601 format so we can use `datetime.fromisoformat()` to convert it to a `date` object. From there you can do whatever you want with the date... print it in your desired format, add days or whatever to it, etc. Sample code is below.

```
times = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "time")
for time in times:
    datetime_string = time.get_attribute("datetime")
    date = datetime.fromisoformat(datetime_string)
    print(date)
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

NOTE: You may need to tweak the CSS selector based on the rest of the HTML on the page to fit your scenario but this will get the date from on the HTML provided.